# Phalcon installation issue on PHP 5.6

Tags: phalcon

I struggling install Phalcon for 2 days but still fail. my server has lasted Direct Admin installed.

below is my installation command

```
cd /root/cphalcon/ext && /usr/local/php56/bin/phpize --clean && /usr/local/php56/bin/phpize && ./configure --enable-phalcon --with-php-config=/usr/local/php56/bin/php-config56 && make
```

which generate error in config.log as below

please suggest how to fix this

Thank so much in advanced.

---

config.log

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.63.  Invocation command line was

    $ ./configure --enable-phalcon

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = hidden
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 20:57:37 UTC 2015

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /root/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1984: checking for grep that handles long lines and -e
configure:2044: result: /bin/grep
configure:2049: checking for egrep
configure:2113: result: /bin/grep -E
configure:2118: checking for a sed that does not truncate output
configure:2184: result: /bin/sed
configure:2318: checking for cc
configure:2334: found /usr/bin/cc
configure:2345: result: cc
configure:2379: checking for C compiler version
configure:2387: cc --version >&5
cc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:2391: $? = 0
configure:2398: cc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) (GCC) 
configure:2402: $? = 0
configure:2409: cc -V >&5
cc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:2413: $? = 1
configure:2436: checking for C compiler default output file name
configure:2458: cc -O2 --fvisibility=hidden   conftest.c  >&5
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-ffvisibility=hidden"
configure:2462: $? = 1
configure:2500: result: 
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h.  */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2506: error: in `/root/cphalcon/build/64bits':
configure:2509: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: Have you tried the instructions on this post? https://blog.phalconphp.com/post/guide-upgrading-to-phalcon-2

Comment: Tried it. most content on that post are guide to upgrade to Phalcon 2.0. if you mean to checkout to 2.0 branch before install. i tried but still failed. i found that master branch is version 2.0.3 which might be lasted...

Comment: 2.0.3 is the latest version hence in the master branch. Running `./install` from the /ext folder should be all you need.

Comment: Tried. the result is ------ [root@server1 ext]# ./install
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
configure: error: in `/root/cphalcon/ext':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. --------- with the same error in config.log

Comment: I'm done. below is checklist to solve my issue

before installation, you should check what your current php version on your server by run "php -v"

Comment: **1.** if you server install multiple version of php, make sure you run the same version between "phpize" and "php-config"

# cd /root/cphalcon/ext && [path to phpize] && ./configure --enable-phalcon --with-php-config=[paht to php-config] && make && make install

in my case
# cd /root/cphalcon/ext && /usr/local/php56/bin/phpize --clean && /usr/local/php56/bin/phpize && ./configure --enable-phalcon --with-php-config=/usr/local/php56/bin/php-config56 && make && make install

Comment: **2.** config php.ini ( make sure you edit correct file )
   add line "extension=[absolute path to phalcon.so]"
   or 
   extension_dir = "[path to extension directory]"
   extension = "phalcon.so"
   
   in my case :
   "extension=/usr/local/php56/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/phalcon.so"

Comment: **3.** file ownership - directory related to phalcon might be "/usr/root/phalcon", "/usr/local/php56/include/php/ext/phalcon" . for me i set to 755

Comment: Great that you got it running!!! I would suggest that you reply to your own post with these instructions so that the solution is easier to find :)